# How to get the longitude latitude of multiple locations saved in db base on a longitude latitude with in a distance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

what is the approach of retrieving all longitude latitude saved in db for locations ,base on a provided longitude latitude provided as an input to a function with in distance in jpa Repository

what i have done is doing so using @query and JPQL 
is there any code i can make use of ,any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

make your Question more clear

First if You want to get some Data based on longitude and Latitude
suppose your Entity class is Location

then you can use like this

```
public List<Location> getLocation(long longitude,long latitude) {
    return locationRepository.findByLongitudeAndLatitude(longitude, latitude);
}
```

or if you want to provide list of longitudes & latitudes then replace the method body with

```
public List<Location> getLocation(List<Long> longitude,List<Long> latitude) { 
    return locationRepository.findByLongitudeInAndLatitudeIn(longitude,latitude);
}
```

Spring Data JPA supports a large number of keywords to build a query. IN and AND